# If a closure as duplicate would lead to a circle, why am I required to review it (it should stay open)?

Tags: bug, duplicate-answers

Reviewing the Close queue as commanded, and I got [How to get the next auto-increment id in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3759008).  When closing as duplicate (as commanded), I got told that:

[image]

This diagnosis is correct; the other question is already closed as a duplicate of this one.  But if the system can work that out, why are humans required to review it.  The system should reject the original duplicate tag.

Clearly, this will be marked 'leave open' by me, but I shouldn't be needing to review it.